# PTP Communication

Tags: c#, sockets, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to communicate with a precision time protocol (PTP) server and build a PTP clock using windows forms and C#. I understand the entire process of a Sync message, then sometimes a followup message, then a delay request message, and lastly a delay response message. Now I need to communicate with the server. WireShark picks up all of the packets that I need, but how can I pick those packets up with C#?

I understand that multicasting is done with IP address 224.0.1.129 on PTP port 319.
My rough outline looks as such:

```
while (true) //Continuously getting the accurate time
{
    if (Receive())
    {
        //create timestamp of received time

        //extract timestamp of sent time

        //send delay request

        //Receive timestamp

        //create receive timestamp

        //calculate round trip time

        //adjust clock to new time
    }
}

private bool Receive()
{
    bool bReturn = false;

    int port = 319;
    string m_serverIP = "224.0.1.129";
    byte[] packetData = new byte[86];
    IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(m_serverIP), port);
    Socket newSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

    try
    {
        newSocket.Connect(ipEndPoint);

        newSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 3000;
        newSocket.Receive(packetData, SocketFlags.None);
        newSocket.Close();
        bReturn = true;
    }
    catch
    { }

    return bReturn;
}
```

Where Receive() is a method that returns a boolean if you received a sync message, and will store the message in bytes eventually. I am trying to use sockets to connect with the server, but my timer always times out, and returns false. I have my PTP server set to send a sync message every second, so I know that my timing out (after 3 seconds) should be able to pick it up.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Just a cursory glance, but maybe don't squelch the exception (empty catch block) and instead let it be thrown up or print it to see what sort of issue is happening.

Also, I think you need to use the ReceiveFrom method rather than Receive given that you're working with UDP.

[another question about some basic UDP stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657984/receive-from-udp-socket-and-send-data-back)

So call ReceiveFrom and [Bind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the socket to the ipEndPoint. Here's roughly what you need:

```
private static bool Receive()
{
    bool bReturn = false;

    int port = 319;
    string m_serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
    byte[] packetData = new byte[86];
    EndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(m_serverIP), port);
    using(Socket newSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp))
    {
        try
        {
            //newSocket.Connect(ipEndPoint);
            newSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);

            newSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 3000;
            //newSocket.Receive(packetData, SocketFlags.None);
            int receivedAmount = newSocket.ReceiveFrom(packetData, ref ipEndPoint);
            newSocket.Close();
            bReturn = true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dear me! An exception: " + e);
        }
    }

    return bReturn;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that also, but no success. The problem isn't that it can't receive (I've done UDP and NTP communications before), it's that it won't find/get what I want it to.